# How to use all in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to write this query using `all`, but it is not valid SQL:

```
SELECT *
      FROM OrderCustPlankLoad ocl
      WHERE ocl.PlankLoadStatusId = 2 and all 
      (Select PlankLoadStatusId from OrderAccountPlankLoad oal where oal.PlankLoadStatusId = 2
      and ocl.PlankClientId = oal.PlankClientId
      )
```

What I want to ensure is that all related records in the related table have a status of 2.

But I don't think I am writing this correctly - SSMS does not like the "All" as well as "ocl.PlankClientId" in the query.

What I am doing is ensuring that all the records are valid before I start processing them.  I don't want to process the rows in `ocl` if there are related rows in `oal` that are not valid.

How do I write this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
      FROM OrderCustPlankLoad ocl
      WHERE ocl.PlankLoadStatusId = 2 and not exists
      (Select 1 from OrderAccountPlankLoad oal where oal.PlankLoadStatusId <>2
      and ocl.PlankClientId = oal.PlankClientId
      )
```

Comment: @Dale K I am answering from my phone. That's why failing to format.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur, I updated formatting

Comment: @Greg Gum thanks a lot. Will try to find a way to format from mobile.

Comment: `(Select PlankLoadStatusId` is pointless, might as well be `(select 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM OrderCustPlankLoad ocl
  WHERE ocl.PlankLoadStatusId = 2
      AND ocl.PlankClientId IN 
            (SELECT oal.PlankClientId 
             FROM OrderAccountPlankLoad oal
             WHERE oal.PlankLoadStatusId = 2
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this which seems to be working:

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderCustPlankLoad ocl
WHERE ocl.PlankLoadStatusId = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM OrderAccountPlankLoad oal
    WHERE oal.PlankLoadStatusId = 5
    AND ocl.PlankClientId = oal.PlankClientId
)
```

Comment: Should be `where oal.PlankLoadStatusId <> 2` in the subquery to ensure all other statuses do not exist.